# implode() :invalid argument passed

Tags: php

```
function submit_data()
    {
        $st_value='';
        $ft_value='';
        $mt_value='';
        $otr_value='';
        $st_details= $this->input->post('check_list');  
        $ft_details= $this->input->post('ft_check_list');  
        $mt_details= $this->input->post('mt_check_list');  
        $otr_details= $this->input->post('otr_check_list');  
        //print_r($st_details);
        $st_value=implode(",",$st_details);
        $ft_value=implode(",",$ft_details);
        $mt_value=implode(",",$mt_details);
        $otr_value=implode(",",$otr_details);

        $index= $this->register->insert_details($st_value,$ft_value,$mt_value,$otr_value); 
        //$this->register->update_details($st_value,$ft_value,$mt_value,$otr_value);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message',$success_message);
        redirect(base_url().'new_register/index/'.$index);  

    }
```

Here is my controller function and i am getting an error message of implode(): invalid argument passed while submiting,How can i intercept the error.

Comment: The second argument should be an array, not an object

Comment: `$this->input->post('check_list'), $this->input->post('ft_check_list'), $this->input->post('mt_check_list'), $this->input->post('otr_check_list')` each of these must be array. `implode()` expect 2nd parameter to be an array. Also update your question with form hmtl so that we can check what you're passing.

Comment: You have 4 calls to `implode()`, which one is getting the error? What's the value of the second argument?

Answer (score 2):

`implode()` method accept second parameter as array. I think you are providing it a string.
Check by `var_dump($st_details);`

Answer (score 2):

As others said, `implode()` uses second parameter as array. You can test your varriable to see if it's an array using `is_array()` or using `var_dump()` to see its details.

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

[var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)